# Do not delete all the keys of the localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In my application I would like that in a moment all the keys of my localstorage will be deleted, with the exception of all the keys that contain the word "wizard".

Commands such as

```
localstorage.clear();
```

will erase everything, and I just want to keep those that have the word "wizard", I have tried in this way, but I get errors because if I delete a match, in the next iteration a key will be skipped, I will get the error that is trying to search a match in a position that will now be null, since it has been deleted. how can I solve that?

this is my code:

```
for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
  //if the key not contain the word "wizard" will be erased
  if( localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)).search("wizard")==-1){
   localstorage.removeItem( localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the `entries` of `localStorage`, and delete the key if the value includes `wizard`:

```
localStorage.foo = 'foo';
localStorage.bar = 'wizard1';
localStorage.baz = 'wizard2';
localStorage.buzz = 'buzz';

Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (!val.includes('wizard')) delete localStorage[key];
});
console.log(Object.keys(localStorage));
```

Result: only `bar` and `baz` keys will remain.

(Cannot post as embedded snippet because stack snippets do not support localStorage)

https://jsfiddle.net/cLm3kg01/

If you want to keep *key names* which contain `wizard` rather than *values* that contain `wizard`, then use `Object.keys` instead of `Object.entries` to iterate over the keys:

```
localStorage.wizard1 = 'foo';
localStorage.wizard2 = 'bar';
localStorage.baz = 'baz';
localStorage.buzz = 'buzz';

Object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key) => {
  if (!key.includes('wizard')) delete localStorage[key];
});
console.log(Object.keys(localStorage));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cLm3kg01/6/

Comment: thanks for your help... It has a problem, look please https://jsfiddle.net/w1794va2/  I add other key to localstorage, and this is deleted too (I updated the link)

Comment: Your `localStorage.variable` does not contain `wizzard`, so it gets deleted - isn't that what you wanted? *I just want to keep those that have the word "wizzard"*

Comment: I just want to keep those that have the word wizzard. Excuse the confusion my language is Spanish.

Comment: Same thing - your `variable` does not have `wizzard`, so it is not kept? If it does not have `wizzard`, you do not want to keep it, right? That's exactly what's happening

Comment: I mean that all the keys that do not have the word wizzard must be deleted. in the end I must keep only the keys that have the word wizzard. you understand me?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. In your edit to the fiddle, your `variable` does not have the word `wizzard`, so it is not kept, just like `foo` and `buzz`.

Comment: ahh you're right I had a confusion, in my real problem, are the keys that contain the word wizzard, the keys, not the value.

Comment: See edit - iterate over the `keys` instead of the `entries`. Please edit your question to clarify that you care about the key names rather than the values.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
  //if the key not contain the word "wizard" will be erased
  if( localStorage.key(i).search("wizard")==-1){
   localstorage.removeItem( localStorage.key( i )  );
  }
}
```

And if you're trying to search the value of item, then your code is fine. But you'll just need to use regular expression with global flag:

```
.search(/wizard/g)
```

With removing item like this:

```
localstorage.removeItem( localStorage.key( i )  );
```

But not this:

```
localstorage.removeItem( localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the items in the `localStorage` in an object, then clear it. Then copy back the required items to the `localStorage`.

```
localStorage.setItem("test", 123); 
localStorage.setItem("wizard", 123); 
var keyToSave = "wizard";

function clearStorageWithoutKey(keyToSave){
   var items = {...localStorage};
   localStorage.clear();
   localStorage.setItem(keyToSave,items[keyToSave]);
   console.log(localStorage);
}
clearStorageWithoutKey(keyToSave);
```